# Add www to URL with and without SSL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I am coding a website that uses SSL for most of the website.

At the moment I'm using a htaccess rule to add www to the URL, see the rule below:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bettingproperties.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.bettingproperties.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

How can I make it so that it will detect https and do the same also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I can do this just by using the following.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bettingproperties.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.bettingproperties.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, which should switch SSL traffic to regular HTTP:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.bettingproperties.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```